# Is it correct to evaluate combinations of two as sum?

Tags: summation, combinations, factorial

I've recently had a look to a problem solution that puzzles me. ANd Ican't make up my mind in order to explain myself why it seems actually to work.

Consider having N unique numbers and find all possible combinations of 2 for these N numbers (without repetition)

i.e. how many distinct couples from a population of distinct subject without repetition

I remember this is expressed as C(N,2) = N!/(N-2)!*2!

$${n \choose 2} = \frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!}$$

The proposed solution was 
SUMMATION for i=0 to N-1 of i

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i  $$

(sorry but I dont know how to express summation here)

Testing the problem using some PHP scripting was successful :

```
function fact($num){
  $factorial = 1;
  for ($x=$num; $x>=1; $x--) 
  {
    $factorial = $factorial * $x;
    }

    return $factorial;
}


for($value=0; $value<=100; $value++){
  $sum = 0;
   for($i=0;$i<$value;$i++){
    $sum = $sum +$i;
        }

        $combinations = fact($value)/(2*fact($value-2));

    echo "Value: $value , Sum: $sum, Comb: $combinations".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Then I remembered that the SUM of the first N integers can be expressed as N(N+1)/2 , so considering N-1 that would be the same as C(N,2) = N(N-1)/2

Found a Math demonstration.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i = \frac{(n)(n-1)}{2} = \frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!} = {n \choose 2}$$

What I'd like now (the question is) : to figure out in my mind (representation) why this summation would be the same of looking for combinations of two....
hope the aim of this question make sense

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: many thanks! awesome notation.. didn't know that !

Comment: If you pick out $2$ numbers from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ you can start with picking out the greatest of both. If it is $n$ then there are $0$ possibilities . If it is $n-1$ then there is $1$ possibility, et cetera. That leads eventually to $0+1+2+\cdots+(n-1)$ possibilities. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

To choose two numbers from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, pick the larger $l$ of you two numbers first, then there remain $l-1$ choices for the smaller number; all in all there are $\sum_{l=1}^n(l-1)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i$ choices possible.

This is by the way the result that on MathOverflow has the top-voted [proof without words](https://mathoverflow.net/a/8847/19077) at the relevant question.

Answer (score 1):

Set-up all $N$ items in a row and give them numbers from $1$ to $N$.

Pick the first item – you can't pair it with any earlier item, because there is no earlier items → $0$ possibilities.

Pick the second item – you can pair it with exactly *one* earlier item → $1$ possibility.

Pick the third item – you can pair it either with the first item or with the second one → $2$ possibilities.

Pick the $i$-th item – you can pair it with any item from $1$ through $(i-1)$ → $(i-1)$ possibilities.

Pick the $N$-th item – you can pair it with any item from $1$ through $(N-1)$ → $(N-1)$ possibilities.

Hence the number of possible unordered pairs is
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^N(i-1) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}i$$

Comment: I tried to answer just the question asked: 'why does this summation result in a number of possible pairs of N items'. The question 'why is it equal $\frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!}$` is somewhat solved by OP, and 'why is  $\frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!}$ the number of pairs' can be easily explained, based on permutations count, but that is quite another story and so I omitted it here.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed.  In fact, that is how [Ibn al-Banna al-Marrakushi al-Azdi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_al-Banna%27_al-Marrakushi) derived the formula.

Consider the set $S = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$.  By definition, $\binom{n}{2}$ is the number of subsets of $S$ with two elements.  We count two-element subsets whose least element was $k$.  If $k = 1$, there are $n - 1$ such subsets since the larger element must be selected from $\{2, 3, \ldots, n\}$.  If $k = 2$, there are $n - 2$ such subsets, there are $n - 2$ since the larger element must be selected from $\{3, 4, \ldots, n\}$.  In general, if $k = m$, there are $n - m$ such subsets since the larger element must be selected from $\{m + 1, m + 2, \ldots, n\}$.  Hence, the number of subsets of a two-element set is 
$$\binom{n}{2} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} (n - k) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} k = \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} k$$

Source:  Victor J. Katz, *A History of Mathematics:  An Introduction*

The argument above is based on Katz's description of al-Banna's argument.  I do not know al-Banna's precise argument.