# How to deduce the combinations formula without using the variations/permutations formula?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In the majority of the math books, When we reach the combinatorial topics,...

The first concept introduced is the variations,

Then,, the permutations,...

And finally the combinations.

I understand that this order could be logical in forder to the deduction of formulas.

The question is:

How to deduce the combinations formula without using the combinations/permutations formulas.

--

### The reason is that I think that the logical sequence by difficulty ascending is 1-Combinations, 2-Permutations, 3-Variations. combinations should be firstly showed. And then permutations an variations.

Comment: You could define combinations recursively by [Pascal's identity](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Pascal%27s_Identity) $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k} + \binom{n-1}{k-1}\,$, then solve the recurrence to derive the closed form formula.

Comment: See my response to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205060/is-it-correct-to-evaluate-combinations-of-two-as-sum/2205080#2205080) to see how [Ibn al-Banna al-Marrakushi al-Azdi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_al-Banna%27_al-Marrakushi) derived the formula for $\binom{n}{2}$.  Next, al-Banna derived the formula $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n - k + 1}{k}\binom{n}{k - 1}$$ I have not seen his derivation, which enabled him to derive the formula for $\binom{n}{k}$.  He then derived the formula for $P(n, k)$ by multiplying the result for $\binom{n}{k}$ by $k!$.

Answer (score 2):

First when speaking about combinations take into account that order doesn't matter, so for example $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{2,1,3\}$ are equal.

A simple approach for defining mathematical formula of combinations would be the following:

We have a set $S=\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$ with $n$ elements and we want to form groupings of size $k$.

Then take one element of $S$ and you will have $n-1$ elements remaining. Take another element and you've $n-2$ elements remaining. Repeat until $n-k+1$ elements are remaining.

$$n\cdot(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1) = \prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(n-i)$$
 as you can see this is the typical variation formula. Since a variation is a permutation of a combination you end up with:

$$\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(n-i)}{k!}$$

But we notice that:

$$\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(n-i)}{k!} = \frac{n!}{k!\cdot(n-k)!} = \frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)\cdot(n-k)\cdots1}{k!\cdot(n-k)\cdot(n-k-1)\cdots 1}$$

So this is the formula where it comes from. Trick is done expanding factorials and understanding that variations are permutations of combinations. Hope you get my approach.

---

As you don't need the standard definition I can show you how to obtain combination formula without the need of variations or repetitions with an example:

Combinations of length $5$ using numbers up to $10$:

$$\frac{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6}{5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1} = 252$$

Mathematically can be viewed as:

$$\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k\cdot(k-1)\cdots1}$$

Comment: @kukox , I´m trying... and... do you think that combinatios should be showed befores pemrutations/variations?. For example the number of combinations usually is lower than the numberr of permutations/variations.

Comment: @MikaIke: Well as commented above variations are permuted combinations, so you need to deal with combinations before of variations to understand these. I think that permutations should be studied before, then combinations and variations.

Comment: @kuk0x, I agree. P - C - V, althoug I´m trying to obtain the combinations formula withoutt using neither permutations nor variations. I´m not sure of obtain it.